# Git Windows Repository Permissions

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I have Git setup on a Windows server all configured using SSH (Bitvise SSH).

I have manually created some bare repositories on the server using an admin account.

When I connect remotely using the same admin account it lets me clone the repo with no issues. However, when I use a user account it cannot find the repository.

So to be clear, this works:

```
git clone ssh://Admin@xxx.cloudapp.net:789/~/Test
```

This doesn't:

```
git clone ssh://User@xxx.cloudapp.net:789/~/Test
```

I've checked all the Windows permissions on the server for the folder containing the repository, 'User' has full access to everything.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: you are missing the error message. What does mean "This doesn't:"? Does bare `ssh` work?

Comment: The error is "Repository not found"

Comment: Perhaps am I wrong but `~` in the uri means the home folder of the user. So perhaps the repository is in the folder of the admin user and not the one of the other user...

Comment: Home directory has been unified across all users. I will try using an absolute path to rule it out when I get home, but I don't think it's that.

Comment: Turns out there was something wrong with my path. Oddly the explicit path that I got to work wasn't what I expected. I was previously using /c/Dev/Repos/Test turns out I didn't need the /c so /Dev/Repos/Test worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but each Git user should have another SSH keys.
Did you use specified SSH keys (for User account) when you tried clone by User account?

Comment: Should have said, I'm using password authentication at this point to take any key issues out of the equation. Ssh is working, I can connect and see the repo with putty just not with the Git commands. It smells like a permission issue, but the windows permissions look fine. Are there separate repo permissions somewhere that I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had the home path of the users set wrong and was also making a mistake with the absolute path. I didn't need the drive letter... So

```
/path/to/repo
```

Worked, but

```
/c/path/to/repo
```

Didn't. Anyway all setup now, I now have a completely Windows based Git server with SSH